How can the singlet wavefunction be used for a triplet calculation?
I am performing a single-point calculation in ORCA to determine the singlet excited state energies. I also want to calculate the triplet state energies, but I've noticed something that seems incorrect.
In the output files, the FINAL SINGLE POINT ENERGY differs between the singlet and triplet calculations, even though they should be the same since I am using the same geometry. The only difference in my input is the use of DOTRIPLET TRUE.
I attempted to use the GBW file from the singlet calculation to initialize the triplet calculation, hoping that using the singlet wavefunction would resolve the issue, but the discrepancy remains. Am I missing something? Does anyone have any recommendations?
Thank you in advance.

I'm a little confused... are you expecting the single point energy of a triplet and a singlet state to be the same if you calculate it on the same geometry?

@isolated. I thought they are referring to ground state energy so they should be the same. Because orca print excited state energies without declaring this. I don't know if I misunderstood something

Okay then, just before I write an answer, I want to make sure I understand what you are doing. What I gather from your question is that you are calculating two (ground state) single point energies on the same molecule at the same geometry, except you are changing the multiplicity (triplet for one calculation, singlet for the other), and these single point energies are different, whereas you think they should be the same. Is that correct?

@isolated I didn't change the multiplicity. I just included in my input  especially in the part '%MDCI'. DOTRIPLET TRUE. What I want to understand, ORCA print the excitation energy for example Root 1 is 1.90 ev then where is the energy of the ground state that they calculated this energy with respect to it. I thought final single point should be the ground state at this minimum so I can calculate the absolute energy from these two values.

Ah, okay, I definitely misunderstood, then. Apologies!
